# Limiting flow direction to D4 instead of using D8 in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hydrology, arc-hydro, hydrology-toolset

Is there a way that I can limit flow direction to D4 instead of having it use D8?

Preferably looking for a way to do it within ArcMap.

Comment: The question you are asked is very short but  it's good question if you explain in more detailed.For example what is D4,D8. Did you try to write a script about this?

Comment: Can be done but 4 remaining are going to be diagonal. Set some cells to nodata, e.g. white ones on a chess board.

Comment: @wetland, if you look up any flow direction tool, it goes over what D8 is: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-flow-direction-works.htm

Comment: For D4, I would just like to limit the direction options to straight north, south, east, and west.

Comment: I've just come across this an need to do something similar. Would it be possible to post the workflow for this please? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let me know if this is what you expecting to see:

[image]

I'll post workflow.

Comment: That is what I was looking for! We decided to stick to D8 and just work around it. But it may be worth posting if other people come to this question.